# If then Else in ASP.NET Repeater with Checkbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, if-statement

Here is my ASP repeater code

```
<asp:repeater id="filterTable" runat="server">
<HeaderTemplate>
    <br/><br/><br/>
    <div class="table-responsive">
            <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" id="table_odd" class="quickordertable table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed grid-table">
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 80px">
                Details
            </th>
            <th style="width: 80px">
                Filter
            </th>
            <th style="width: 30px">
                Qty
            </th>
            <th style="width: 60px">
                Include In Order
            </th>
        </tr>

</HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
        <td><%#Eval("Details")%></td>
        <td><%#Eval("FilterType")%></td>
        <td><%#Eval("Qty")%></td>
        <td><asp:CheckBox ID="orderPartNumber" Checked="true" runat="server"/><asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenPartNumber" Value ='<%#Eval("PartNumber")%>'></td>
    </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate>
        </table>
    </div>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I have an ASP ItemTemplate with a field of `<%#Eval("GenuineOnly")%>`

If field `GenuineOnly` contains a value, (Or is not Null) Then I want to show this code

`<td>GENUINE ONLY</td>`

Else I want to show this code

```
<td><asp:CheckBox ID="orderPartNumber" runat="server"/><asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenPartNumber" Value ='<%#Eval("PartNumber")%>'></td>
```

I've tried a number of different ways but can't seem to get the syntax right! Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please show your code some little bit more because from this piece of information I cant analyse your situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using this way:

```
<td>
    <asp:Panel runat="server" Visible='<%#Eval("GenuineOnly").ToString().Length > 0 %>'>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="orderPartNumber" Checked="true" runat="server" />
        <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hiddenPartNumber" Value='<%#Eval("PartNumber")%>' />
    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:Panel runat="server" Visible='<%#Eval("GenuineOnly").ToString().Length == 0 %>'>
        GENUINE ONLY
    </asp:Panel>
</td>
```

Comment: First, I have added newline for code clarity. Now, I removed it

Answer (score 1):

I assume you can add Table/Td as per your need.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptr" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptr_ItemDataBound">
<ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblGenuineOnly" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("GenuineOnly") %>' />
        <asp:CheckBox ID="orderPartNumber" runat="server"/>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenPartNumber" Value ='<%#Eval("PartNumber")%>' runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
```

Code behind

```
protected void rptr_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        Label lblPartNumber = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblGenuineOnly");
        CheckBox chkPart = (CheckBox)e.Item.FindControl("orderPartNumber");

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(lblPartNumber.Text.Trim())) {
            //Display GENUINE ONLY in any label like lblPartNumber.Text = "GENUINE ONLY"
            chkPart.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            chkPart.Visible = true;                
        }
    }
```

Comment: Now it not showing any checkbox or "GENUINE ONLY" text

Comment: you can just reverse the conditions like

      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(lblPartNumber.Text.Trim())) {
            //Display GENUINE ONLY in any label like lblPartNumber.Text = "GENUINE ONLY"
            chkPart.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            chkPart.Visible = false;                
        }

Comment: Ok, let me double check